# Android - Choose default tab for action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried to develope an android application with action bar, I have three tabs in the app, the problem is that when I run the application the left tab choosen as default, how can I choose the middle tab as default tab, I want to show the middle tab when the user run the application, here is my code:

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "search", "image", "wiki" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new Search();
    case 1:
        return new Image();
    case 2:
        return new Wiki();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I've never worked with tabs, but I think it works the same as list navigation.

Have you tried to use this code below?

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```

In your case, position might be 1.